# Take a screenshot of a specific element from a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, screenshot

I need my Chrome extension to take a screenshot of the whole page/tab, excluding an element that I have injected in it after the closing `</body>` that is overlaying everything else.

Currently, I take the screenshot from a background script with the following code:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.type === 'cheese') {
        setTimeout(() => {
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, { format: 'png' }, (src) => {
                sendResponse({ src });
            });
        }, 10);

        return true;
    }
});
```

The only solution I've found so far to exclude that element is hiding it momentarily before taking the screenshot, but sometimes it still appears, thus the `10ms` delay in the code above. That reduces the frequency of the issue, but doesn't fix it completely and, anyway, is just a workaround that I'd like to get rid of.

Before, I was using `requestAnimationFrame` to send the screenshot request to the background script only after the element has been hidden, but surprisingly, that didn't fix the issue, that's why I tried with that `setTimeout` instead.

Please, note the element I want to get rid of on the screenshot is on top of a relevant area of the page, so cropping the captured area is not an option, as I won't be able to see whatever is behind that element.

I took a look at the remote debugging protocol, where the closest I found was [`Page.captureScreenshot`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-captureScreenshot), which accepts a `clip` parameter that would crop the screenshot, but still capture the overlay.

Comment: I think your content script should simply send the message in the next paint frame after hiding the element e.g. inside requestAnimationFrame callback. As for mimicking devtools, see the documentation for chrome.debugger API and chrome remote debugging protocol.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was using `requestAnimationFrame` to send the screenshot request to the background script only after the element has been hidden, but surprisingly, that didn't fix the issue, that's why I tried with that `setTimeout`. I also took a look at the remote debugging protocol, but I cound't find what I need. Also, it's worth mentioning that taking the screenshot using Chrome Dev Tools, when the overlay is visible, makes the screen go gray and takes a few seconds, which doesn't happen if that element is not visible.

Comment: [captureScreenshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot) with a rectangle obtained via [getSnapshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOMSnapshot#method-getSnapshot)?

Comment: @wOxxOm As I said, that would crop the snapshot, but still capture the overlay that is covering the relevant elements, so that's not an option, unfortunately. Anyway, I actually want to capture all the visible area of the page, but without that element showing up.

Comment: @Danziger I have a similar issue, did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: @AziCode Unfortunately I didn't. Hiding and showing the elements you don't want on the screenshot seems to work most of the time, but sometimes it won't work properly (in my case the screenshot is refreshed when scrolling the page, so if you scroll up and down quickly you might still get the unwanted element on some screenshots). You can either increase the time you wait before taking that screenshot or track the unwanted element position and, once you take the screenshot, check the color of some pixels where that element should not be. If it's actually there, you refresh the screenshot.

Comment: @Danziger interesting thank for your reply. Were you able to delay taking the screenshot? did you do that using setTimeout ? I have an error when I  try to use setTimeout ? how did you manage to delay taking the screenshot ?

Comment: I didn't have any issues with that. The code above works just fine to me. What does your error say?